# Laravel canonic condition on extends

Tags: laravel, view

Hello I have 4 layouts to use 4 user types for the same view
I tried this but it's not working without any error just showing me `layouts.dashetudiant` for the user type parent wish expect `'layouts.dashparent'`

```
@extends( Auth::user()->type === 'professeur' ? 'layouts.dashprof' :(Auth::user()->type === 'admin' ? 'layouts.dash' : (Auth::user()->type==='parent'? 'layouts.dashparent':'layouts.dashetudiant') ))
```

I had before this one and it's working really good but now I have a fourth type of users

```
@extends(Auth::user()->type === 'professeur' ? 'layouts.dashprof' : (Auth::user()->type === 'admin' ? 'layouts.dash' : 'layouts.dashetudiant')  )
```

Comment: Why not a switch statement before `@extends`?

Comment: avoid nested ternaries - jimmy dugan

Comment: @Nasa what do you means?

Comment: @lagbox i'm a true noob and to be honest this is one of the solution I found "Okey" instead of creating many views

Comment: are you going to need to do this check in more than one view?

Comment: yes I will need to put it in 3 views @lagbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```php
<?php
$layout = 'layouts.dashetudiant'; // default
switch (Auth::user()->type) {
    case('professeur'):
        $layout = 'layouts.dashetudiant';
        break;
    case('admin'):
        $layout = 'layouts.dash';
        break;
    case('parent'):
        $layout = 'layouts.dashparent';
        break;
}
?>

@extends($layout)
```

to avoid nested ternsries for readability , and probably solve your problem as well

Comment: I tried it but it give me "syntax error, unexpected '$layout' (T_VARIABLE) (View: C:\laragon\www\projetv2\resources\views\editprofile.blade.php)"